# In Firefox, which add-on processes the webpages first?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Let's say I have two add-ons, A1 and A2. A1 blocks x, y and z content from web sites, and A2 blocks y, z and w. How do I know, which one processes first the webpage, so I could turn off the unnecessary blocking in the other one?